# how I can import easyeditor Jquery plugin as ES-6 into my project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vite

I am importing this [lib](http://habibhadi.com/lab/easyeditor/default-example.html) into my laravel project:

```
npm i easyeditor --save
```

And I load it into my vite setting:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import inject from "@rollup/plugin-inject";

import { readdirSync,lstatSync } from 'fs';
import { resolve } from 'path';


function getFilesFromDir(dir) {
    const filesToReturn = [];

    function walkDir(currentPath) {

        if(lstatSync(currentPath).isFile()){
            filesToReturn.push(currentPath);
            return;
        }

        const files = readdirSync(currentPath);
        for (let i in files) {
            console.log(files[i]);
            const curFile = resolve(currentPath, files[i]);
            if(lstatSync(curFile).isDirectory()){
                walkDir(curFile);
                continue;
            }
            const file = resolve(currentPath, files[i]);
            filesToReturn.push(file);
        }
    }

    walkDir(resolve(__dirname, dir));
    return filesToReturn;
}


const js = getFilesFromDir('./resources/js');

const paths = [

    ...js,

    'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',

    'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
    'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js',
  
    "node_modules/easyeditor/src/easyeditor.css",
    "node_modules/easyeditor/src/jquery.easyeditor.js"
]

console.log(paths);

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input:paths,
            refresh: true,
        }),
        inject({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
        }),
    ],
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            external: [
                "js/modules/*",
            ],
            include:[
                'assets/js/utils.js'
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

But I want instead of loading as:

```
@vite("node_modules/easyeditor/src/jquery.easyeditor.js","assets/js/myjs.js")
```

To use it as ES-6 module:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
// Import easy editor here
```

But as I can see the lib is not exported as a module:
https://github.com/im4aLL/easyeditor/blob/master/src/jquery.easyeditor.js

How I can do this?